# How to loop foreach seperatly php

Tags: php, arrays

i  want to filter results from my array using php

my array 1

```
    {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "nectarine",
    "lactose": "Moderate"

    },
    {
    "id": 27,
    "name": "peach, white",
    "lactose": "None"
    },
```

this is my array 2

```
{
"0": "None",
"4": "Moderate"
}
```

i want to get None results and Moderate results seperatly from array 1,

this is my current set ,

how can i do this. pls advice

Comment: What is the purpose of array 2? Do you want to separate array 1 into 2 separate arrays or are you wanting a new array that just contains the count of each type of object?

Answer (score 0):

Create two new arrays: "none" and "moderate" and iterate through array1 and push the id of each into the respective new arrays based on the value associated with "lactose". This will give you two arrays with only the ids of those items in each category and you can then use that to identify the name of each using the original array. Not sure how array two figures into the story, but this will give you a way of separating the items of array1 based on the lactose content. I can post the code required if you are still stuck. but you should try doing it yourself to learn about array_push() and other php stuff.